# Is there a way to create a lambda equivalent of this function call in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda, equivalent

Using this function and call:

```
  def top(df, n=3, column='tip_pct'):
      return df.sort_values(by=column, ascending=False)[:n]

  tips.groupby('smoker').apply(top)
```

I was able to obtain this output:

[image]

Is there a way to show the same output using a lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is a one-liner, you can just copy the `return` expression into the body of the lambda.

```
tips.groupby('smoker').apply(lambda df, n=3, column='tip_pct': df.sort_values(by=column, ascending=False)[:n])
```